# Java swing - when cancel button clicked don't loop

Tags: java, swing

I have a gui, that is having a Login prompt added.

```
while(notValidLogIn){
        LoginPrompt.getDetails() //a static method that 
}
```

Hwoever, the loginPrompt is a Jdialog, with a parent JFrame. How can I stop looping of cancel clicked, I could put System.exit(0) in cancel action performed. But don't want to stop everything, I want something like :

```
while(notValidLogIn && LoginPrompt.isNotCancelled()){
  LoginPrompt.getDetails(); //a static method that creates an instance of login JDialog()
}
```

Comment: Can you rewrite your question more clear? WHat are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent project I was working on, I've implemented an event based solution. The idea is `JDialog` notify to its parent `JFrame` how the login process went and this last one may or may not continue its execution. This way I have no loops and keep separate responsibilities: The schema would be something like this:

#### LoginEvent:

This is the event itself. Not that complicated:

```
class LoginEvent extends EventObject {

    public static final int LOGIN_SUCCEEDED = 0;
    public static final int LOGIN_FAILED = 1;
    public static final int LOGIN_DIALOG_CLOSED = 2;

    private int id;

    public LoginEvent(Object source, int id) {
        super(source);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

#### LoginListener

An interface to handle these `LoginEvent`s:

```
public interface LoginListener extends EventListener {

    public void handleLoginEvent(LoginEvent evt);

}
```

#### Login Dialog

This class has to mantain a `List` with subscribed `LoginListeners`:

```
class LoginDialog {

    List<LoginListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    JDialog dialog;
    JButton accept;
    JButton cancel;

    public void show() {
        //create and show GUI components
    }

    public void close() {
        if(dialog != null) {
            dialog.dispose();
        }
    }

    ...

    public void addLoginListener(LoginListener loginEventListener) {
        if(!listeners.contains(loginEventListener)) {
            listeners.add(loginEventListener);
        }
    }

    public void removeLoginListener(LoginListener loginEventListener) {
        listeners.remove(loginEventListener);
    }

    public void dispatchLoginEvent(LoginEvent evt) {
        for(LoginListener loginListener: listeners) {
            loginListener.handleLoginEvent(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Adding action listeners to `accept` and `cancel` buttons:

```
    accept.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // validate login data
            if(loginValid) {
                dispatchLoginEvent(new LoginEvent(dialog, LoginEvent.LOGIN_SUCCEEDED));
            } else {
                dispatchLoginEvent(new LoginEvent(dialog, LoginEvent.LOGIN_FAILED));
            }
        }
    });

    cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            dispatchLoginEvent(new LoginEvent(dialog, LoginEvent.LOGIN_DIALOG_CLOSED));
        }
    });
```

#### Subscribing a LoginListener

In your `JFrame`:

```
    final LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog();
    dialog.addLoginListener(new LoginListener() {

        @Override
        public void handleLoginEvent(LoginEvent evt) {
            if(evt.getId() == LoginEvent.LOGIN_SUCCEEDED {
                dialog.close();
                //continue execution
                return;
            }
            if(evt.getId() == LoginEvent.LOGIN_FAILED) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Login failed!");
                return;
            }
            if(evt.getId() == LoginEvent.CLOSE_LOGIN_DIALOG) {
                dialog.close();
                // do something when this dialog is closed
            }                
        }
    };
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(notValidLogIn && LoginPrompt.isNotCancelled()){
  LoginPrompt.getDetails(); //a static method that creates an instance of login JDialog()
}
```

If this loop is inside another thread other than the EDT(event dispatch thread), then you can use `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable())` function: `invokeAndWait()` blocks the current thread until the EDT is done executing the task given by it. This option is particularly used while we want to await an execution of a thread for taking confirmation from user or other input using `JDialogue/JFileChooser` etc

```
while(notValidLogIn && LoginPrompt.isNotCancelled()){
    SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
          LoginPrompt.getDetails() ;
       }
    });

  }
```

**Note:** *re-stating for emphasizing*: you should ensure that this loop is executing inside another Thread: such as using  an extended class of `Runnable`, or by means of anonymous class:

```
new Thread()
{
   // other code of your context
  public void run()
  {
      while(notValidLogIn && LoginPrompt.isNotCancelled()){
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
              LoginPrompt.getDetails() ;
           }
         });
      }
   }
}.start();
```