# Java Swing: main class wait until JFrame is closed

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe, invokeandwait

I need some help with a simple java application which makes use of two jframe to get some input parameters. Here's a sketch of my code:

```
//second jframe, called when the button OK of the first frame is clicked
public class NewParamJFrame extends JFrame{
  ...
}

//first jframe
public class StartingJFrame extends JFrame{
  private static  NewParamJFrame newPFrame = null;
  private JTextField gnFilePath;
  private JButton btnOK;

  public StartingJFrame(){
            //..
    initComponents();
  }

  private void initComponents(){
     btnOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        try{
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
           public void run() {
               try {
               newPFrame = new NewParamJFrame();
               newPFrame.setVisible(true);
               } catch (Exception e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
         });
        }
        catch(InvocationTargetException e2) {} 
        catch(InterruptedException e1){}
        dispose();
      }
  }

  public String getText(){
       return gnFilePath.getText();
  }
}

public class Main {
  private static StartingJFrame begin = null;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     try{
        EventQueue.invokeAndWait(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                try {
                    begin = new StartingJFrame();
                    begin.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch(InvocationTargetException e) {} 
    catch(InterruptedException e1){}

    String s= begin.getText();

    //...use s ...
  }
}
```

The call to getText() causes a NullPointerException. I want the main class to wait until the frames are closed but I don't know how to do. I'm using swing for the first time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I want the main class to wait until the frames are closed but I don't
>   know how to do. I'm using swing for the first time.

If I understand your problem correctly, you need `StartingJFrame` to stay waiting until `NewParamJFrame` is closed and then continue its execution. If this is the case then it won't happen because `JFrame` doesn't support modality. But `JDialog` does, so you can have just one `JFrame` and do the parameters request in a `JDialog` whose parent is this `JFrame`.

For a better explanation about modality, take a read to [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html).

Also take a look to this topic: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice/9554657#9554657)

In any case you'll probably face a new problem: what should the `JFrame` do if the user closes/cancels the dialog withouth input any parameter? How could this `JFrame` know what just happened in that dialog? One approach is described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19975959/java-swing-when-cancel-button-clicked-dont-loop/19977196#19977196). You'll see the example is about a login dialog but the problem is similar to this one: How could a dialog notify to its parent frame on how the process went?

Comment: thank you very much!Now I better understand what @Holger meant.I'll try to do like you suggest, hope to solve in this way :)

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to wait for close without modifying the code flow is to use a modal `JDialog`. So you have to change your `StartingJFrame` class to make it a subclass of `JDialog` instead of `JFrame`, and add the following to the begin of its constructor:

```
super((Window)null);
setModal(true);
```

Then the `setVisible(true);` invocation on the `StartingJFrame` instance will wait until the dialog has been closed and hence the `invokeAndWait` invocation will wait too.

Answer (score 2):

> The call to getText() causes a NullPointerException.

Because, `gnFilePath` of `JTextField` is `null`.

```
private JTextField gnFilePath;

public String getText(){
       return gnFilePath.getText();// NullPointerException is throw here.
}
```

To avoid `NPE`, you need to initialize `JTextField` and `JButton` like below.

```
  private JTextField gnFilePath=new JTextField();
  private JButton btnOK=new JButton()
```

Comment: I do it in the initComponents method..I think it is a problem dealing with thread, it seems like the main thread goes on and doesn't wait

Comment: IF you do it at initComponetns, than you need to call it first.

Comment: What do you mean?Where do I have to call it? I already call initComponents in the constructor of the frame..i've tried to call initComponents also in the main before begin.setVisible(true) but the problem still remains

Comment: @user3008214 `invokeAndWait` does not execute the supplied Runnable immediately. So when you call `String s= begin.getText();`, begin is not yet initialized and equals to `null`. But even you add some delay before running `begin.getText()` and get rid of NPE, you'll likely to get empty string, because you have to wait for user to enter the text. Moreover, you may not call `getText()` on the main thread. Do everything on EDT using events.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting this:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame{
    MyWindow(){
        setSize(300, 200);
        setLayout(null);    
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JButton b = new JButton("Close");
        b.setBounds((300-80)/2, (200-30)/2, 80, 30);
        //
        final MyWindow frame = this;
        b.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev){
                    synchronized(frame){
                        frame.notify();
                    }
                
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                    frame.dispose();
                }
            }
        );
        //
        getContentPane().add(b);
        
        setVisible(true);
        
        synchronized(this){
            try{ 
                this.wait();
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){ }
        }
    }


    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new MyWindow();
        System.out.println("You are here");
    }
}
```

The code above is checked.

Answer (score 1):

Using a JDialog is probably the simplest solution, but in some cases it's desirable to have a JFrame, for example to show the window in the taskbar. Using a synchronization mechanism as suggested by Octavio is a way to achieve this, here is an alternative using a CountDownLatch blocking the main thread until the frame is closed:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(300, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
    });

    latch.await();
    System.out.println("Main thread released");
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use a loop (preferably do-while loop) to put a frame on hold until the other frame closes or hides. Make sure to break the loop or increment the variable used for the loop by specific amount when the other frame is disposed or hidden. This way you can keep your `StartingJFrame` class to remain as a subclass of `JFrame`.

```
    do {
        if (changeLog.isVisible()) {
        } else {
            changeLog.dispose();
            break;
        }
    } while (hold < 1);
```

or

```
    do {
        if (changeLog.isActive()) {
        } else {
            break;
        }
    } while (hold < 1);
```

The first one would require the previous frame to be hidden (`JFrame.HIDE_ON_EXIT` or `Window.setVisible(false)`) before the codes can be run. The last one would require the previous frame to be "disposed" (`JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_EXIT` or `(subclass of JFrame).dispose()`. Add any of those codes on `StartingJFrame`, though, since you created a `NewParamJFrame` in that class and have the corresponding field(s) set to `private`.